# Beep-Codes definition for ASUS motherboard

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, uefi

I'm having a hardware failure when booting and I need to know the exact beep-code definitions for the [Asus M5A97 LE R2.0](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_LE_R20/). 
Could someone provide me the beep-codes of that motherboard? I can't find them in the ASUS webpage and other beep-codes that I've found are not exact for this UEFI.

Comment: They should be exact.  ASUS uses the same beep-codes for accross all their product lines.

Comment: *at least until you go as far back as to ~2006 designed boards, [then](https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/P5LD2-X/HelpDesk_Manual/) floppy controller becomes important.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The manual exists on [Asus' support site](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM3+/M5A97_LE_R2.0/E7460_M5A97_LE_R2.pdf#page=54) and it contains the beep codes on page 2-16 ("Chapter 2: Getting Started"):

[image: Asus M5A97 Le R2.0 Beep Code Table]

Comment: Thanks but can you provide the exact url, the manual, or say the steps (what buttons to click) to get inside that manual page?, also continuous means LONG?

Comment: Yes 'continuous' in this case means long.  As for providing a direct link -- Nope, it's there, and it may change, and the dynamic link to it would just die in the future. :)  When you look up the downloads for your board on the "Download" tab, after you pick an OS, scroll the badly designed (sub)panel down to see more choices (like "Manuals").

Comment: "Hardware component failure" The most helpful error message of them all.

Comment: I use ctrl + f to search for text on my Web browser window

Answer (score 2):

[(Motherboard) ASUS BIOS beep codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20170119225704/http://www.asus.com/US/support/FAQ/1029959)

> - One short beep - VGA detected, No keyboard detected

- Two short beeps - When using Crashfree to recover BIOS, the new BIOS is successfully recognized.
- One continuous beep followed by two short beeps then a pause (repeated) -  No memory detected
- One continuous beep followed by three short beeps -  No VGA detected
- One continuous beep followed by four short beeps -  Failure of Hardware component