# Common beep codes reference

Tags: motherboard, post

What are the common beep code alerts for most BIOS out there?

---

**Author note**: I'm posting this QA after finding an excelent resource leading from [this QA](https://superuser.com/questions/783082/beep-codes-definition-for-asus-motherboard)

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong with the question rather than simply downvoting it, thanks.

Comment: I agree with you. Those sheriffs around here do strange things. I upped it.

Comment: Read through the ***[help]*** would help you guys understand the "sheriffs" and the down votes.

Comment: @fixer1234 That kind of reasonable thing for downvoting a question it's exactly what I was asking for on my first comment. I did a search, but obviously it was not enought accurate. Sorry

Comment: @fixer1234 Sorry, we are missunderstanding. My comment tried to be a "thank you" message. I think your explanation (telling this question is a duplicate) was polite and neccesary to a newcomer like me to understand why the community **may** be downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: The original source is [computerhope](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm), I've pasted and prettified some content here to avoid making a link-only answer**

---

A list of common beep codes for common BIOS out there:

## AMI BIOS beep codes

> Because of the wide variety of different computer manufacturers with this BIOS, the beep codes may vary.

```
   Beeps | Description
 1 short | DRAM refresh failure
 2 short | Parity circuit failure
 3 short | Base 64K RAM failure
 4 short | System timer failure
 5 short | Process failure
 6 short | Keyboard controller Gate A20 error
 7 short | Virtual mode exception error
 8 short | Display memory Read/Write test failure
 9 short | ROM BIOS checksum failure
10 short | CMOS shutdown Read/Write error
11 short | Cache Memory error
 1 long, 
 3 short | Conventional/Extended memory failure
 1 long,
 8 short | Display/Retrace test failed
two-tone
  siren  | Low CPU Fan speed, Voltage Level issue
```

## AWARD BIOS beep codes

> Because of the wide variety of different computer manufacturers with this BIOS, the beep codes may vary.

```
  Beeps | Description
1 long,
2 short | Indicates a video error has occurred and the BIOS cannot
        | initialize the video screen to display any additional
        | information.
  Other 
  beeps | RAM problem.
```

If any other correctable hardware issues are found, the BIOS displays a message.

## Dell beep codes

```
     Beep Code     |     Description
7 beeps (repeated) | Bad processor (CPU)
```

For other Dell beep codes, please refer to [Dell's Beep Codes and PSA Diagnostics Chart page](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/w/desktop/3624.beep-codes-and-psa-diagnostic-chart).

## IBM BIOS beep codes

> Because of the wide variety of models shipping with this BIOS, the beep codes may vary.

```
    Beeps  |   Description
  No Beeps | No Power, Loose Card, or Short.
   1 Short | Normal POST, computer is ok.
   2 Short | POST error, review screen for error code.
Continuous
      Beep | No Power, Loose Card, or Short.
 Repeating
Short Beep | No Power, Loose Card, or Short.
 One Long,
 one Short | Motherboard issue.
 One Long,
 Two Short | Video (Mono/CGA Display Circuitry) issue.
 One Long,
 3 Short   | Video (EGA) Display Circuitry.
Three Long | Keyboard or Keyboard card error.
 One Beep,
 Blank or
 Incorrect
   Display | Video Display Circuitry.
```

## Feel free to add more BIOS to this list!

Comment: Here are some more ==> http://www.pchell.com/hardware/beepcodes.shtml