# Asus Mainboard gives unknown Beep Code (not on official website listing of buzzer codes)

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios

I have a Asus P8H67-m pro.

Over the weekend I was (again) trying my luck with installing Hackintosh, and while restarting and trying different BIOS settings,I had to reset BIOS settings by pulling the battery multiple times. One time, my PC failed again to go further then the first screen, so I shut it off, removed the power and the battery for some time. When I put it back and started the PC, nothing happened and the screen stayed completely black. No beep or anything. Only the Power LED was turned on and the fans where turning, otherwise no indication the PC even started.

I then figured out when I press reset instead of turning it only on and off, I do get a buzzer signal. It's 2 tones, one short and high, one long and lower.

Upon looking at the ASUS website, I found that this code was not specified anywhere.
Can anyone help me with this situation?

Heres the listing of buzzer codes im referring to:
https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1029959/

(also referenced in another post on this page [Beep-Codes definition for ASUS motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/783082/beep-codes-definition-for-asus-motherboard))

***EDIT:***

The situation changed drastically - withouth any changes, the PC suddenly does start, but still only a reset, like the beeps.

meaning: the PC works as expected at the moment, besides the fact that a cold start does nothing, and only if i then press the reset button, the pc starts as expected

Comment: Looks, sounds and smells like a RAM problem to me. I assume your PC is a laptop (you mention removing the battery), so, if the RAM stick(s) aren't soldered, can you remove them or it, and if there is more than one, try to boot with only one, then the other, trying each one in a different socket?

Comment: It's a desktop, i was talking about the cmos Battery. I rule out the RAM Sticks since i tried 4 different Ram Sticks in 4 different Ram Slots. Also, there is a specific Beepcode for Anormalities in the Ram :/

Comment: Is the time correct in BIOS? In Europe, we switched to Daylight Saving Time this weekend, so you may have to adjust date and time manually. If you don't, and you manage to install your macOS on this PC, you'll find it difficult to update or install software.

Comment: I cannot access BIOS, thats part of the problem. The screen is completely black and i don't even have the possibility to enter setup.

Comment: Since it's a desktop PC, can you check on the GPU? Could be there's something wrong with it. One thing you can try first: unplug the power chord from the PC, and keep your finger on the Power button for about 30 seconds, then release pressure, plug the power chord back on and try to boot.

Comment: Also did that already, the GPU is not installed at the moment, but i tried it with the GPU too, just in case the internal GFX is having problems..

Comment: The mobo brand notwithstanding, the explanation given here (https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/unable-to-enter-bios-or-boot-windows-black-screen.1727557/post-12196173) makes sense and is worth investigating, I think.